# Is component.js compatible with node-webkit?

Tags: requirejs, node-webkit

Since node-webkit use requirejs() for browser context and require() for node context (may co-exist  in same JS) I have doubts it will work well with component.js. I would like to switch to component.js but will they go well together?

Now I am using Aura.js http://aurajs.com/ which has very similar concept to component.js.
But component.js seems to have a much bigger eco-system.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine they would work just fine. Component's built files define their own "require" function at the top of the scope, so any built-in "require" function would be invisible from within that scope.

I'm actually looking into node-webkitizing a js app I build w/ component, so I'll let you know how it goes.

---

**Update:** Initial investigation reveals some fiddling might be required for maximum satisfaction. My results, with my non-trivial single page app, using ace editor, angular, jade, lesscss, etc.

- default configuration: works just fine
- setting toolbar: false; application hangs...
- setting toolbar: false and node: false; works just fine

This may just be a bug of node-webkit and unrelated to using component. I'll keep you posted.

---

**Update 2:** It looks like building component in "standalone mode" (`component build -s name`) works without hiccups. This means that the built file is scoped, and window.require is unaffected. Therefore, if you want to use node's require, you would using window.require from within your script.